# How can I enable WinHTTP trace logging in Server 2012 R2 for viewing raw HTTP commands and application details?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-monitoring, trace, winhttp

I have an application running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 system and the app leverages winHTTP for various network requests.  It's not able to communicate with another server on the network and I suspect (but can't confirm) that there's a network issue.

All of the troubleshooting commands/tools that I'm familiar with leverage WinINET so I don't have an easy mechanism for verifying connectivity.  As such, I'd like to increase available logging.

Back in Server 2008, I could run something like:

```
netsh winhttp set tracing trace-file-prefix="C:\Temp\dpws" level=verbose format=ansi state=enabled max-trace-file-size=1073741824
```

I got that from [this microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/bb648687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

When I try running the same command on Server 2012, I get an error (or perhaps information statement?):

[image]

I tried following the instructions and tried running `netsh trace start scenario=InternetClient` but the resulting ETL file didn't look quite right (perhaps just newbie error on my side).  When I reviewed the etl in network monitor 3.4, I saw what looks like system calls:

[image]

...but I'm not necessarily interested in that -- I want to see the information occurring at the network connection and HTTP levels.  Is there an easy way to see that?

Mr. Google also pointed me to [this article](https://blogs.iis.net/richma/winhttp-tracing-options-for-troubleshooting-with-application-request-routing) but none of the event viewer messages seemed to help or capture the type of information I'm looking for.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem as yours, this guide was helpful, i atleast now see stuff in it but not in the most helpful format. The short summary is

- Update the parser profile to use windows parsers
- Filter to HTTP

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/08/24/using-netsh-to-analyze-wininet-problems-in-windows-7-and-windows-8/